# toggle true or false in an property of an object created using factory function

Tags: javascript

I used to have this constructor and a prototype that could toggle an object.status between true or false. here:

```
function Book(title, author, length, status){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.length = length;
    this.status = status;
}

Book.prototype.toggleStatus = function (){
    this.status = !this.status;
}
```

Now I'd like to create the prototype in a Factory Function. Here is as far as I've gone:

```
const Book = function (title, author, length, status) {

            const toggleStatus = () => status = !status

           return {title, author, length, status, toggleStatus}
```

If I call the someObject.toggleStatus() I receive on the log the inverted boolean status, but it does not change the **Value** on the kvp of the object itself, which is my end goal here. If possible I'd like this to be made using prototype.

Comment: This works https://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Book%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20(%40title%2C%20%40author%2C%20%40length%2C%20%40status)%20-%3E%0A%20%20toggleStatus%3A%20-%3E%20%40status%20%3D%20not%20%40status%3B - ignore the coffeescript left side. It uses ES2015 keywords though so it's a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the handler reassign the property of the returned object:

```
const Book = function (title, author, length, status) {
  const book = { title, author, length, status, toggleStatus: () => book.status = !book.status };
  return book;
};
```

Another option (which is weirder) which is closer to your original code which reassigns the variable name inside the closure would be to make `status` a getter instead:

```
const Book = function (title, author, length, status) {
  return {
    title,
    author,
    length,
    get status() {
      return status;
    },
    // add a setter too if needed
    toggleStatus: () => status = !status
  };
};
```

If you want to use a prototype in addition to a factory function, use `Object.create` to create an instance from the prototype:

```js
const Book = function (title, author, length, status) {
  const b = Object.create(bookProto);
  return Object.assign(b, { title, author, length, status });
};
const bookProto = {
  toggleStatus() {
    this.status = !this.status;
  }
};

const b = Book('title', 'author', 7, true);
console.log(b.status);
b.toggleStatus();
console.log(b.status);
b.toggleStatus();
console.log(b.status);
b.toggleStatus();
```

Comment: Hey CertainPerformance, this worked and solved my immediate problem. I'm very thankful.

But, I'll edit my question, because doing it your way doesn't seem to add a prototype, which is what I was trying to figure out as well. Or am I wrong?